# Intermittent KeyError raised and can not reproduce it

Tags: python

I tried to reproduce it with some simpler functions but didn't succeed. So the following code shows the relevant methods for a KeyError which get's thrown by our production servers, a lot.

```
class PokerGame:
...
    def serialsNotFold(self):
        return filter(lambda x: not self.serial2player[x].isFold(), self.player_list)

    def playersNotFold(self):
        return [self.serial2player[serial] for serial in self.serialsNotFold()]
...
```

And here is the Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pokernetwork/pokertable.py", line 945, in update
    try: self.game.historyReduce()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3949, in historyReduce
    self.turn_history = PokerGame._historyReduce(self.turn_history,self.moneyMap())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 1323, in moneyMap
    money = dict((player.serial,player.money) for player in self.playersNotFold())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3753, in playersNotFold
    return [self.serial2player[serial] for serial in self.serialsNotFold()]
KeyError: 21485L
```

- self.player_list is a list with serials
- self.serial2player is a dict which maps serials to Player objects

Now it shouldn't be possible that the KeyError is raised in playersNotFold because therefore the same error had to be raised in serialsNotFold, which it gets not.

I asked my 2 peers and the guys on #python but no one was able to even gues how this can happen.

If you need the full source: https://github.com/pokermania/poker-network/

**EDIT:**
The Problem was that we printed traceback.format_exc(limit=4) which limits from the top instead of the bottom. The last 2 calls where hidden, so it looked like playersNotFold raised the exception.

Here is a full trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokernetwork/pokertable.py", line 704, in update 
    try: self.game.historyReduce() 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3953, in historyReduce 
    self.turn_history = PokerGame._historyReduce(self.turn_history,self.moneyMap()) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 1327, in moneyMap 
    money = dict((player.serial,player.money) for player in self.playersNotFold()) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3757, in playersNotFold 
    return self.serial2player[serial] for serial in self.serialsNotFold()] 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3754, in serialsNotFold 
    return filter(lambda x: not self.serial2player[x].isFold(] self.player_list) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pokerengine/pokergame.py", line 3754, in <lambda> 
    return filter(lambda x: not self.serial2player[x].isFold(] self.player_list) 
KeyError: 1521
```

I'm sorry for wasting your time :/

Comment: Since you posted the github repository, pointing the specific commit or branch HEAD that contain the error may be useful.

Comment: Is this socket based game ? Or just players communicate asynchronously?

Comment: it's in the master branch. github is 2 weeks behind or so.. i will update it now.

Comment: self.player_list is list or property? property that returns self.serial2player.keys()

Comment: no, it's a list of serials (Int or LongType)

Comment: Ha. I had this feeling that the traceback was somehow limited.

Comment: The only time we get a traceback (really, why no one ever post tracebacks?) and it was truncated, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use threads and self.serial2player gets modified by a different thread.